# A Bonferroni correction should consider tests that are not part of scientific hypothesis?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, bonferroni

I have a multiple regression, with a specification like this (using R notation):

```
lm(nohusk ~ Line + (habitat + hemisphere + n.ind)^2 + I(n.ind^2) )
```

For those not familiar, (habitat + hemisphere + n.ind)^2 implies all second-order interaction between habitat, hemisphere and n.ind. I(n.ind^2) is the square of n.ind.

For the purpose of my study, I am only interested in knowing if interaction between n.ind and habitat is significant. The other terms are there to control for potentially confounding variables. But nevertheless R generates a p-value for every one of them.

For purposes of Bonferroni correction, does this regression counts as 1 test (1 hypothesis) or as 9 (number of p-values produced)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For purposes of Bonferroni correction, does this regression counts as
>   1 test (1 hypothesis) or as 9 (number of p-values produced)?

You are interested in one p-value, **1 hypothesis**, as the others are completely out of the research scope (you can not see them and be happy).

You count only those hypothesis checks that relate to the problem under study.